# probability measure times a dilation

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We consider the following probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$\mu = Leb\vert_{[0,1]} \times \delta_0$. Furthermore the following dilation, say $d$, is defined as $(x,0) \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(\delta_{(x,f(x))}+\delta_{(x,-f(x))})$ where $f$ is an arbitrary function. definite the probability measure $\nu$ as $\nu = \mu d$.

I have two questions: What exactly is a 'dilation' is this context? Can someone explain me the constructed measure $\nu$ in words? I do not have a picture in mind...

Comment: What is the difference between $\delta_a$ and $\delta_{(a,b)}$?

Comment: the first dirac measure is one dimensional (as part of a two-dimensional measure) and the second is two dimensional

Comment: And what exactly $\times$ mean?

Comment: $\mu$ is the product measure of these two measures